# Mass install OS

Tags: server, kernel, iso, pxe

I'm a little stuck on this issue and not sure what path to take and how.

I have a clonezilla image of a custom Ubuntu. That image needs to be running on remote supermicro servers worldwide with different hostname/ip each.

One thought I had is to create an auto preseed install but I'm not sure how to make it so that it would match the current state of the ubuntu clone. Setting up PXE is also not possible to set in every site as some of give very limited access on the switch which wouldn't allow grand DHCP.

Is there a humanly inpainful way of creating an ISO preseed out of the clonezilla clone? Is there aproach to all of this?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Preseed does not work with cloning. Are you firm on cloning? Or are you open to other methods?

Comment: Absolutley open. I'd even rather have a different route.

Comment: Are these bare-metal installs? Or VM/Container installs? How many instances?Dozens? Thousands? If you had to duplicate your customization on one clean-install, how many hours would it take?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's 100 bare metal servers. Not sure what you mean by "duplicate my customization"